# writing list to file from Dataframe: key error

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I'm stumped - I have two csv files I've uploaded as dataframes using the Pandas package, and then (among other things) I take one column from the csv file out as a separate list (column 'key' as a list of strings [[keyval1, keyval2, keyval3].

What I'm struggling to de-bug is that writing to a new text file using logfile.write and an iterator for the length of the list keeps giving me a key error stating:

raise KeyError('no item named %s' % com.pprint_thing(item))
KeyError: u'no item named key'

But it only does it in the function "inoutflows" (and works with no errors in the function "susstring"
the code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

popkey1 = pd.read_csv("popkey1.csv", delimiter='\t')
matrix = pd.read_csv("flight1quart.csv", delimiter='\t')
listof = []
listof = popkey1['airport'].tolist()

#print popkey1
#print listof

a = 0
logfile = open("flighttest.txt", 'a')


##### CODE FOR SUSCEPTIBLE IN AND OUTFLOWS ALGORITHM ######
def susstring (l, marker):
    x = marker
    for y in range (0, len(l)):
        if x != y:
            if y != (len(l) - 1):
                logfile.write(str(l[y]) + "to" + str(l[x]) + " + ")
            else:
                logfile.write(str(l[y]) + "to" + str(l[x]) + " - ")
        else:
            a = y
    for sy in range (0, len(l)):
        if x != sy:
            logfile.write(str(l[x]) + "to" + str(l[sy]) + " - ")
        else:
            a = y
    logfile.write("siflow" + str(x + 1))

def inoutflows(li, marker2):
    numx = marker2
    logfile.write("INFLOWS:\n")
    for numy in range (0, len(li)):
        if numx != numy:
            logfile.write(str(li[numy]) + "to" + str(li[numx]) + " = City_" + str(numy+1) + "_Susceptible * " + str(matrix[li[numy]].ix[numx]) + "\n")
        else:
            a = numy
    logfile.write("OUTFLOWS:\n")
    for ny in range (0, len(li)):
        if numx != ny:
            logfile.write(str(li[numx]) + "to" + str(li[ny]) + " = City_" + str(numx+1) + "_Susceptible * " + str(matrix[li[numy]].ix[numx]) + "\n")
        else:
            a = ny
    logfile.write("siflow" + str(numx+1) + " = City_" + str(numx+1) + "_Susceptible * 0.05\n")


for x in range (0, len(listof)):
    logfile.write("City" + str(x+1) + "_Susceptible(t) = City" + str(x+1) + "_Susceptible(t - dt) + (")
#   susstring(listof, x)
    logfile.write(")) * dt\n")
    logfile.write("INIT City_" + str(x+1) + "_Susceptible = " + str(popkey1['population'].ix[x]) + "\n")
    inoutflows(listof, x)
```

The popkey1 csv file is a file with three columns; key, airport, population
and the flight1quart is a matrix with travel times between different keys.

Any tips on what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated - I've scoured stackoverflow and documentation but I don't know why it works for one function but not the other.